# How to Convert key/value pair String to a JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json

How can I covert key=value pair string to json object

input :

```
test = one
testTwo = two
```

Output should be json object

```
  "test":"one","testTwo":"two"
```

Comment: Please try doing this on your own. If you fail, research why you are failing and correct your code. If you still fail, show the code which is failing and the measures you took to correct it and how others can reproduce your problem. Maybe then someone can help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is `input` a string? You could first split it by `\n` to get an array of key/value-pairs, and then split each pair by `=`, to get an array of the key and the value.

```js
var input = `test = one
testTwo = two
testThree = three
testFour = four`;

var output = input.split('\n').reduce(function(o,pair) {
   pair = pair.split(' = ');
   return o[pair[0]] = pair[1], o;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer David Hedlund. If I have more than two rows how could I achieve this

Comment: @dileepH: You can have any number of rows.

Comment: Thanks @David Hedlund

Comment: Great... you saved my day :). Just to those who want to exclude empty lines as well as comment lines (starting with # as per Java properties file), you can add these if statments `if(pair === '' || pair.startsWith('#')) { return o}`. Also `\n` is a windows character, if you want this to work with linux's new line character too change the `split` to `split(/\r\n|\r|\n/)`

Answer (score -1):

The safest way to do it is JSON.parse(string)

Comment: Doesn't this only work when `string` is proper JSON?  IIRC, `JSON.parse` returns an object made from a JSON string.